# independence of three random variables

Tags: probability-theory

If we have three random variables $A$, $B$, and $C$. Can we have a situation where (A,B) together are independent of C and at the same time (A,C) together are independent of B? If yes,  can someone please provide an example of such a situation?

Comment: Any three indpendent random variable will do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stated properties hold if and only if $A,B,C$ are together independent, so examples are plenty.

Answer (score 0):

Of course.  For example, let the sample space be $[0,1]$ and let $A(\omega)$, $B(\omega)$, and $C(\omega)$ be the first, second, and third digit of the binary expansion of $\omega$, respectively.